# Error 91 en tiempo de ejecución: Variable de tipo Object o la variable de bloque With no está establecida vb6

Tags: vb6

Hola buenos días Tengo este fragmento de código en visual basic que al compilar me da error

```
Sub ImprimirEtiquetasPorLote(NumeroLote As Long)
Dim StrSQL As String, _
    ElRs As Object, _
    MiRpt As Object, _
    StrPedidoPaquete As String, _
    IntPaginas As Integer, _
    RptConcatenado As RptEtiqPaqueteria ' DDActiveReports2.ActiveReport
mvarStrConexion = MiStrConexion
StrSQL = ObtenerSQL("ETIQUETAS PARA PAQUETERIA (POR LOTE)")
    StrSQL = Replace$(StrSQL, "$$NUMEROLOTE$$", NumeroLote & "  AND Production.Packages.CreatedByUserName<>'Auto_VLM'")
Set ElRs = RecordSetLectura(StrSQL)
**If Not ElRs.EOF Then**
```

Se queja en la línea que os pongo con asteriscos.
He mirado que la variable StrSql me la rellena correctamente pero no veo el fallo. ¿Me podéis ayudar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de `RecordSetLectura(StrSQL)`? a ver si es que la variable `ElRs`va  a estar vacía

Answer (score 0):

Hice pruebas y de esta forma funciona:

```
Sub ImprimirEtiquetasPorLote(NumeroLote As Long)
    Dim StrSQL As String, _
        ElRs As Object, _
        MiRpt As Object, _
        StrPedidoPaquete As String, _
        IntPaginas As Integer
        ', _    RptConcatenado As RptEtiqPaqueteria ' DDActiveReports2.ActiveReport
    mvarStrConexion = MiStrConexion
    StrSQL = ObtenerSQL("ETIQUETAS PARA PAQUETERIA (POR LOTE)")
        StrSQL = Replace$(StrSQL, "$$NUMEROLOTE$$", NumeroLote & "  AND Production.Packages.CreatedByUserName<>'Auto_VLM'")
    Set ElRs = RecordSetLectura(StrSQL)
    If Not ElRs.EOF Then
        Debug.Print "Funciona..."
    End If
End Sub

Function ObtenerSQL(str As String) As String
    ObtenerSQL = "Any..."
End Function

Function RecordSetLectura(str As String) As Recordset
    '...
End Function
```